# Dynamicaly animate elements css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So, I'm coding a roulette that spins sideways (right to left) and I want to know if there is any way I can dynamically use @keyframes, so I can use the translateX() with values according to the round result (The Roulette is in a background image). E.g: The round result is 5. The client receives the result from the server and the roulette translates X pixels to stop in the corresponding number.

Here is the roulette code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { socket } from "../../App.js";

import "./roulette.css";

export default class Roulette extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = socket;
    this.roulette = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      result: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundPositionX: (this.roulette.current.offsetWidth - 78) / 2
    });
    this.socket.on("roulette.roll", position => {
      //TODO: Retrieve from the server how much pixels should be translated  
});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-r flex items-center justify-center">
        <div ref={this.roulette} className="roulette relative">
          <div
            style={{backgroundPosition: this.state.backgroundPositionX + "px" + "0"}
            className="roulette-bg h-full w-full" //The roulette background image, that is suposed to translate when the result is give is in this div
          ></div>
          <div className="roulette-marker absolute"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes you can do it by storing the result recieved from the server into the js variable and use it as desired.

Comment: Alright, but how do I use js variables in CSS?

Comment: Or the best way is if your are fetching the result by PHP for example you can directliy write css as `.class{ height : <?php echo $fetch['height']?>}` this will change the height dynamically.

Comment: but I don't want to change the height

Comment: Yes i  know i just gave you an example. you can also do it for `transform : translateX(<?php echo $fetch['data']?>)`,

Answer (score 1):

You could set it in `componentDidMount()` sort of like this:

```
export default class Roulette extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.socket = socket;
    this.roulette = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      result: null,
      backgroundPositionX: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundPositionX: (this.roulette.current.offsetWidth - 78) / 2
    });
    this.socket.on("roulette.roll", position => {
        this.setState({
            backgroundPositionX: position
        });
      //TODO: Retrieve from the server how much pixels should be translated  
});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-r flex items-center justify-center">
        <div ref={this.roulette} className="roulette relative">
          <div
            style={{backgroundPosition: this.state.backgroundPositionX + "px"}
            className="roulette-bg h-full w-full" //The roulette background image, that is suposed to translate when the result is give is in this div
          ></div>
          <div className="roulette-marker absolute"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or you can use js to set the style of an element on the page using `ElementCSSInlineStyle` functionality. It's discussed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style).

I believe you would put something like this in your `componentDidMount()` (using translate like @yuri-gor mentioned):

```
const bgElement = window.document.querySelector('.roulette-bg');
bgElement.style.transform = 'translateX(42px)';
```

Comment: Okay, but as it's a roulette it spins from time to time, so how can I make it spin again, not only one time?

Comment: I think that would depend on how `socket` works in your app. Ideally, you should be able to make a an additional method in the component, something like: 

`spinTheWheel() { this.socket.trigger("roulette.roll") }` 

Then when `this.spinTheWheel()` is called, it will update the state because `this.socket.on("roulette.roll"...` is still watching for that event to fire.

Comment: So, i did whay you said and it works, but only one time

Comment: Since it spins multiple times but only when the server sends the result to the client, I need it to translate multiple times when it's triggered and always return to the initial position at the end

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements correctly - you need CSS [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), not keyframes.

```css
transition: transform 5s;
```

```js
element.style.transform = 'translateX(42px)';
```

Note that it's better to animate via changing transform - it will be rendered smoother.

Comment: The question is about dynamically changing the data  and you cannot use `transition: transform 5s;` because `transition` property only specifies the time.

Comment: @KunalRaut I believe the `transition` style is there so when that transform of  `translateX(42px)` takes place it occurs in an smooth/animated sort of way, rather than just immediately applying the transform on render

Comment: so please try to add it in the comments or this way it claims as a wrong asnwer.

Comment: how can i make it happens more than 1 time?

Comment: By using the property `animation-iteration-count`.